# Deploy the asp.net MVC 2 web application to the IIS 7.5 getting issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-7.5

I have developed the asp.net mvc web application. whereas my macine is configured with IIS 7.5. I want to deploy my web application with source code to the IIS so that i can attache the process and debug it run time. I choose this way because few functionality , like file copy and file create not performing after simple publish.

I tried by ,
Create the web application in IIS 7.5 manager. installed ASP.NET utility. As i browsed , I got asked by to enable directory browsing. 
Which i enabled. where as in IE I found file structure which definitely did not want. I expected direct my LogOn page which is configured in globle.asax after deployment.

What else i need to check. or is any step i have missing?
I am using Visul web developer 2010 express edition to develop the application.
Please guide me.

Comment: please any guidlines...?

Comment: Seems its the big challenge to deploy MVC site on IIS 7.5. i found its not that easy and direct method to deploy . I every time struggle with this stuff and everytime need to face issue like install aspnet, add user and permissions, application pool, assign port... so many things. it is kind of bullshit...what u say guys?